# How to take one value from one list and apply it on all values in another list

Tags: python, list, loops

For some reasons I can't find out why the code isn't working.
I want to calculate the distance between each one value form the list and all the other values.
like let's say I take the first index from my list down rar[1] = (2927, 6312)
I want to know it distance to it self (which is 0) and all the other values in the lists.

That's why I want to make a loop in which the first point don't change till the second loop with the second point is finished with the action. at the end I want to get a list that have sublists contain distances for each value to the other. like this :

distance = [ [0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4] ]

in which 0 is the distance between the point itself to the point itself .
1 is the distance between the first point and the first value in the list
2 is the distance between the first point and the second value in the list....

Thank you so much in advance.

```
rar= [(2925, 6597), (2927, 6312), (2934, 6545), (2938, 7412), (2941, 6456)]

templist=[]
distance=[]
for i in range(len(rar)) :
    firstpoint = rar[i]
    for q in range(len(rar):
       secpoint = rar[q]
       zipz = np.array(list(zip(firstpoint,secpoint)))
       nan = round(np.linalg.norm(zipz))
       templist.append(nan)
    distance.append(templist)
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Error, or the output is wrong?

Comment: the output was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear how do you compute the distance between two elements but I assume the norm of the difference should do it. Here is a small example on how to do it, while keeping the code simple and minimal using list expressions:

```py
import numpy as np

rar      = [(2925, 6597), (2927, 6312), (2934, 6545), (2938, 7412), (2941, 6456)]
distance = [[round(np.linalg.norm(np.array(a)-np.array(b))) for b in rar] for a in rar]
print(distance)
```

Output:

```
[[0.0, 285.0, 53.0, 815.0, 142.0],
 [285.0, 0.0, 233.0, 1100.0, 145.0],
 [53.0, 233.0, 0.0, 867.0, 89.0],
 [815.0, 1100.0, 867.0, 0.0, 956.0],
 [142.0, 145.0, 89.0, 956.0, 0.0]]
```

Comment: I'm so stupid I cant believe I forget to compute the difference, Thank you for opening my eyes that was really helpful.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)